# Categorized Random Questions in Quiz 4.x module of Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

What is the flow to create questions for a quiz that allows Categorized Random Questions in Quiz 4.x module? I cannot find any documentation at all in this regard.

Saving a quiz with that option takes me to the 'Manage Questions' page with an 'Add a category' option. Trying to add any new category (that I intend to associate with my questions later) throws a 'The term name you entered doesn't match any registered question terms'error. What are the registered question terms and where do I see them/create them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go in Drupal (i use v6.19, Quiz v4.0) to Administer/Content management/Taxonomy and create a vocabulary (eg Question Category), within that you can create terms (eg simple, medium, hard).
Then in question Edit, you should see a new drop down - question category, and select simple, med, or hard for that question.
once you have done that for a few questions, go to your quiz and select Categorized random questions under Randomize Questions. Then you will be asked to allocate the no of simple questions etc
it looks very flexible to me and is exactly what we need.

Comment: Figured that out.Good thing you answered though.